# Silverlight - Would like to know how to bind Observable collection with radio button list

Tags: silverlight

i am new in Silverlight .
I have a observable collection in my view model with list of objects . how do i bind with Radio button group ?

I have tried below , but its not acting like radio button group .

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TableItemTemplate">

            <StackPanel  Width="auto" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <RadioButton  Margin="1,1,1,1"
                           >
                </RadioButton >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources> 

<ListBox Margin ="3,3,3,3" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding OptionLIst}"   
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TableItemTemplate}"
                         >
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the GroupName attribute to the radiobutton

```
GroupName="myGroup"
```